# GPT partition errors on boot - ZFS FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, zfs, gparted

My system appears to be running fine and I'm just trying to clean up errors. That said...

On boot, I get the following errors for all drives in a 24 disk storage enclosure:

```
GEOM: diskid/DISK-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Z1F1XG5S: the primary GPT table is corrupt or invalid.
GEOM: diskid/DISK-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Z1F1XG5S: using the secondary instead -- recovery strongly advised.
GEOM: da3: the primary GPT table is corrupt or invalid.
GEOM: da3: using the secondary instead -- recovery strongly advised.
The zpool using the drives loads and works fine. concontrol devlist shows the drives. gpart show does NOT show the drives. gpart recover /dev/da3 returns an invalid argument error (as expected)
```

All drives are identical. FreeBSD 10. I have a second server with the same configuration and it doesn't have this problem. They are essentially the same system.

I've looked around and can find all the troubleshooting above, but nothing that's provided a solution to make the errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been in this situation myself, but as a start you can try the `gpart recover` for the drives which corruption is reported.

I also advise reading the [following thread](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/gpt-table-is-corrupt-or-invalid-error-on-bootup.12171/).